# How do I do cross-domain http requests in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, sencha-touch

So I'm developing a Sencha (Javascript) app which needs to make Ajax http requests to a REST service that is already in place on a different domain. I need a solution to be able to make POST, PUT, and GET requests from my Sencha javascript to that service. I have no control over the service so I cannot make any changes on that end. I have heard of HTML5's new postMessage() method, but I am unsure how to use or if I am even able to use it to do what i want. Of course, I could disable browser security while in development but that is not a permanent solution. Any suggestions?

In particular, if someone could inform me of the use(s) of the postMessage method, I would be most grateful.

Comment: Cross-domain requests are not possible, especially if you can't change anything about the other service. Of course if you're using something like PhoneGap then that's a whole different story; in that case, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response is JSON, you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). If you are posting, use a hidden Iframe.

Comment: It's pretty brain-dead simple - give the Iframe and name, set the target of the form to the iframe. The URL will be the other domain's POST url. You can attach an onload event to the iframe that will tell you when your post is complete. Leave the iframe visible for testing, then set the height and width to zero when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a serverSide Proxy (PHP, servlet ....) wich will dispatch your cross domain  request , pull the response , then return  the result to your javascript on client side .